# Plot values in .m file from C++

Tags: c++, matlab, plot, octave

I have looked extensively in the net, yet not found exactly what I want.

I have a big simulation program that outputs results in a MATLAB M-file (let's call it res.m) and I want to plot the results visually.
I want to start the simulation with C++ many times in a row and therefore want to automatize the plotting of the results.

I come up to two options:

1. Execute from C++ an Octave or MATLAB script that generates the graph.
   -> Haven't found anyone who managed to do so
2. Use the Octave source files to read the res.m file and output them after with whatever plotting C++ tool. 
   -> Theoretically possible but I get lost in those files

Is someone able to solve this? Or has a better, easier approach?

Comment: I've read your question three times but still don't understand what you are trying to ask. You can run compiled C++ programs from Octave using system/popen/popen2 and so on or the other way around.

Comment: Typically, `.m` files are intended to contain matlab / octave source code, not "data". Do you mean that you have a c++ simulation program which produces a different matlab / octave script at each iteration? (and from what I understand, that part is not your code, so you don't have control over the m-file produced, is that right?)

Comment: You haven’t found anyone that managed to run MATLAB from C++? You should look again, this is officially supported and well documented functionality. I’m sure Octave does too.

Comment: Yes! I want to run display .m data in a plot

Comment: Do you want to write a C++ routine to execute a MATLAB script? How do you want to handle the output, maybe an image file? Wouldn't it be better to consider calling the C++ executable from the MATALB IDE? I often think it's sad seeing people downvote a question because they don't understand it. I have a hard time to understand it, too. But I'd rather ask before judging.

Comment: @Y.Chang The C++ program is for not only executing the script but also for running the Simulation many times. I've seen the Matlab IDE but i spent to much time trying to find the files.

Comment: @sernar If so, then you should try the MATLAB's C++ API approach, which will be more efficient than your picked answer. However, if that's an acceptable solution for your case, so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to execute through the terminal.

I didn't manage to actually run a octave script from my c++ program directly, but there is a way around messing with/through the terminal and a extra Octave file. I used in my cpp:

```
string = "octave myProgr.m"
const char *command = str.c_str();
system(command);
```

myProgr.m is the script that plots the res.m file

Comment: You don't have to go through a std::string to call system

Comment: And by the way, your answer 'to go through the terminal' is just wrong. There is no terminal involved here